# Does Rust have an equivalent of -Ofast -march=native?

Tags: rust

Does Rust have an equivalent of GCC's C `CFLAGS="-Ofast -march=native"` compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To optimise for the native CPU, you can use

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native"
```

I think LLVM optimises for speed (or more specifically, throughput) by default; I couldn't really find documentation on this, but this is what the [source code](http://llvm.org/doxygen/CostModel_8cpp_source.html) suggests.

You should be able to select a different cost model using e.g.

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native -C llvm-args='-cost-kind=latency'"
```

but I haven't tried this, nor do I know any details about the effect of this switch.

Comment: I believe the `'` around `-cost-kind=latency` have to be removed. At least with my tests, I got `unknown commandline argument if I included the single quotation marks.